# Ruby on Rails maps

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I am able to show locations and markers on google maps using the gem Gmaps4Rails and lat,lng derived from the db.

Now I am looking for guidance on how to enable a user to create markers by simply dropping a marker on the map interface and dragging it to fine tune locations. Internally the location can be stored as lat,lng or address.

Comment: There's a good chance this book has an answer to your question:

https://gumroad.com/l/GoSiy

Answer (score 0):

This is also fairly simple. You need to set a **dragabble** variable that would instantiate everytime the marker is dragged to some other location on the marker. There would be a event listener that will keep track of all the events on the corresponding marker. When the marker is placed a particular position the map will set the marker position to the new latlang location using the ***setMarkerPosition()*** method.

Here is a brief code:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=xxx;hl=en" type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>       
       var draggable_marker = null;

       $(document).ready(function() {
          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_div'));
            map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());

            draggable_marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(42.6976489, 23.3221545), {draggable : true,title : "Place this marker to your location");

           GEvent.addListener(draggable_marker, 'dragend', function() {  
              RubyGmap.setPosition(draggable_marker); 
           });
           GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, latlng, overlaylatlng){  
              RubyGmap.setMarkerPosition(draggable_marker, latlng); 
           });
          }
       });
</script>



<div id="map_div" style="width:720px;height:420px;" ></div>
```

**RUBY**

```
RubyGmap = {    
setPosition: function(marker) {
    $('#latitude_field').val(marker.getLatLng().lat());
    $('#longitude_field').val(marker.getLatLng().lng());
},
setMarkerPosition: function(marker, latlng) {
    SELECTED = true;
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    marker.setLatLng(latlng);
    RubyGmap.setPosition(marker);
}
}
```